# Where are my "new" tabs?

Tags: bug, status-deferred, new-nav, user-interface

Yesterday, while logged in to Stackoverflow, I added new tabs for tags which interest me.

I clicked save, renamed the tabs, clicked save again, but today they are gone.

Is there something else I have to do to save these or are they in fact not saved at all and reset after time? Making them temporary essentially.

Comment: Tabs are saved in the browser, they said, so maybe you switched computers or somehow cleared out that data.

Comment: They are saved in the browser, for now.

Comment: Now they are server-stored.