# New Tab Bug - New / Custom Tab keeps disappearing

Tags: support, new-nav

I've found [this thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309072/where-are-my-new-tabs) which seems appropriate but I'd like to ask **how** tabs are stored. I rarely empty my cache, I rarely delete cookies . . . is this a localStorage thing (been clearing that out recently for testing stuff at work)?

This is on Firefox Developer Edition, across my work laptop (Windows 8.1) and home PC (Windows 10). I use FF Developer Edition on both, and my history is synced between both machines.

Could this be a bug (the tag on this question was forced on me, not sure what would suit it better)?

Comment: Does this help: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312434/a-quick-new-nav-update

Comment: Appreciated, I was able to follow the links and copy my local tab (which was still stored, thankfully) to the server. Sorted!